# Инициализация вектора пар целых чисел

Tags: c++11, c++

Есть такой код, из него я думаю понятно что я хочу сделать.

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >* grid;
grid->push_back(std::make_pair (0,0));
grid->push_back(std::make_pair (0,120));
grid->push_back(std::make_pair (0,240));
grid->push_back(std::make_pair (0,360));
grid->push_back(std::make_pair (211, 0));
grid->push_back(std::make_pair (211,120));
grid->push_back(std::make_pair (211,240));
grid->push_back(std::make_pair (211,360));
grid->push_back(std::make_pair (422,0));
grid->push_back(std::make_pair (422,120));
grid->push_back(std::make_pair (422,240));
grid->push_back(std::make_pair (422,360));
```

Компилятор ошибок не выводит, но при отладке приложение крашится на первой же строчке push_back(). В чем может быть проблема и есть ли другой способ ее решения?

Comment: Уберите звездочку, замените `->`, которые вам подставила ваша любимая IDE, на `.` (точки). Также разберитесь на будущее, что означает `std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >*`, и в чем отличие этого типа от `std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >`.

Comment: А можно инициализировать такой вектор чем-то подобным?
grid = {{0,0}, {1,1}...}

Comment: @LiGhT_WoLF: можно, но с отличием указателя от объекта вы всё же разберитесь. А то ваша фраза звучит как «Я чё-то не понимаю, что такое скрипичный ключ. А можно смодулировать в дорийский лад?»

Comment: переменная grid не инициализирована 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых надо убрать звездочку после `std::vector<>`.

Во-вторых, лучше использовать список инициализации:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> grid = {
  {0,0},
  {0,120},
  {0,240},
  {0,360},
  {211, 0},
  {211,120},
  {211,240},
  {211,360},
  {422,0},
  {422,120},
  {422,240},
  {422,360},
};
```